# Можно ли узнать из реестра информацию о работе прикладных программ с файлами пользователя?

Tags: windows, реестр, windows-xp

Есть неактивный реестр Windows XP. Можно ли узнать, сохранилась ли в реестре информация о работе прикладных программ с файлами пользователя? Если да, то каким образом?

Comment: Если такой функционал существует, то узнать можно из **документации** производителя. Например, MS office может сохранять историю открытых файлов в ветвях "Recent File List". Естественно, эта информация доступна на **microsoft.com**. Для других программ гуглите, либо обратитесь в саппорт.

Answer (score 0):

В Windows прикладная программа не обязана работать с реестром, тем более что-то там хранить. Многие программы запоминают несколько последних открытых файлов и тому подобную информацию, но часто хранят ее не в реестре, а где-то у себя в .ini или .xml. Фактически многие разработчики последнее время неохотно пользуются реестром потому что

1) среди пользователей распространилось странное мнение, что записывать в реестр плохо, это засоряет систему, и такие программы являются чуть ли не вирусами, и

2) многочисленные чистильщики реестра часто просто удаляют данные, которые не могут распознать. В результате пользователи начинают скандалить в саппорте что у них программа внезапно перестала работать, при этом не упоминая малозначительный факт, что перед этим они "оптимизировали и ускорили" систему очередной приблудой из интернета.

Так что если конкретное приложение хранит свой список последних файлов в реестре, то вы его достанете. А нет, стало быть нет.

Чтобы достать, проще всего подменить файл реестра на какой-нибудь тестовой системе. Иначе надо брать hex редактор и вручную разбирать структуру реестра. Или искать по строкам, в общем достаточно муторное занятие.